# C++ error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used

Tags: c++, opengl

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RageBotGamingEngine, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Sprite.cpp
1>c:\users\nha\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ragebotgamingengine\ragebotgamingengine\sprite.cpp(51): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Above is what the output logs say. 
Below are some related files that could be involved with this problem:

**Sprite.cpp**

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Vertex.h"

#include <cstddef>

Sprite::Sprite()
{
_vboID = 0;
}


Sprite::~Sprite()
{
if (_vboID != 0) {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vboID);
}
}

void Sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
_x = x;
_y = y;
_width = width;
_height = height;

if (_vboID == 0) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
}

Vertex vertexData[6];

//First Triangle
vertexData[0].position.x = x + width;
vertexData[0].position.y = y + width;

vertexData[1].position.x = x;
vertexData[1].position.y = y + height;

vertexData[2].position.x = x;
vertexData[2].position.y = y;

//Second Triangle
vertexData[3].position.x = x;
vertexData[3].position.y = y;

vertexData[4].position.x = x + width;
vertexData[4].position.y = y;

vertexData[5].position.x = x + width;
vertexData[5].position.y = y + height;

for (int i; i < 6; i++) {
    vertexData[i].color.r = 255;
    vertexData[i].color.g = 0;
    vertexData[i].color.b = 255;
    vertexData[i].color.a = 255;
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Sprite::draw() {
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

//This is position attribute pointer
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
//This is color attribute pointer
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I have tried to find the problem but I'm relatively new to OpenGL, SDL, & C++ & as you can imagine it has been a huge hassle because of the fact that the OpenGL wiki isn't exactly easy to follow & consistent. Just about any help would be very much needed as well as appreciated.

I'm trying to create a Game Engine (obviously I'm pretty much un-skilled & lack the time to develop this project)

Comment: You have two members named `color`...

Comment: @chris can you please elaborate. I'm fairly new to C++

Comment: @nhabbott your `struct Vertex` contains three member variables.  And you're trying to name two of them `color`.

Comment: One `color` in `Vertex` is an instance of `Color`. The other `color` is an array. Which one is `someVertex.color` supposed to refer to?

Comment: @DrewDormann Ok, I fixed that problem but then it says `sprite.cpp(51): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used`

Comment: @nhabbott do you have a new question now?  It sounds like the current version of the question posted here is no longer current.

Comment: @DrewDormann look at this one again

Comment: Do you know what "uninitialized" means?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) ` maybe ?

Comment: @DrewDormann No, could you elaborate?

Comment: @al-eax Yes, it is that part of the code but I don't know what the error means or how to fix it.

Comment: @nhabbott just gibt i a value: `i = 0`

Comment: @al-eax Do you mean `for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)`

Comment: Nope, your array starts by 0 and holds 6 values, first index is `vertexData[0]` up to `Vertex vertexData[5];`
`for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` will iterate from 0 ti 5

Comment: @al-eax Nope that didn't fix it

Comment: @nhabbott are u sure ? same error message ? Please save your file, clean your project, restart your IDE. Maybe your programming environmant cached the old file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i; i < 6; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
```

You declared variable 'i' but forgot to initialise the variable, so it could have any arbitrary value, not necessarily '0'

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why i keep missing this stuff. +1